# What is the difference between Binance Beacon Chain & Binance Smart Chain

Tags: bsc, binance

What is the difference between **Binance Beacon Chain** & **Binance Smart Chain**

Answer (score 0):

The new beancount will be a BNB chain. It includes a BNB beacon chain and a BNB smartchain. its based on beancount. its an ethereum based network. however, its remains EVM compatible. it can be used for smart contracts on existing applications.